# Scintillanet, how to save its text to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, savefiledialog, scintilla

I am programming a code editor in C# using visual studio and I use scintillaNET as the text editor in my program, now I want the user to be able to save the text from the editor to a file. If I used RichTextBox, the code for saving the file would have been:

```
richTextBox.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Now I tried it for my scintilla editor:

```
scintilla.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

but I got error: ScintillaNet.Scintilla does not contain a definition for SaveFile and no extension method SaveFile"...

What's the appropriate code/method for saving text from Scintilla editor to a file. Can someone tell me?
Thank you

Comment: There's no built-in method, and I'm not really sure why you'd need one - scintilla is not a rich-text editor.

Comment: It's not a richtextbox, so you can't expect it to have the same methods as a richtextbox. Check the scintillia documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing with ScintillaNET and found a way to do it.

```
public void SaveToFile(string filename)
{
     File.WriteAllText(filename,"");
     using(StreamWriter strwriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(filename))
     {
         strwriter.Write(this.TextArea.Text);
     }
}
```

Comment: Ya, your right using disposes it automatically. I'll update my code

Comment: Great solution ... Works perfectly.  But, not really a ScintillaNET solution.

Answer (score 0):

ScintillaNet control has no a kind of "*Save-Text-Contents-To-File*" method...

Instead, You have to get the text contents with this property:

[ScintillaNET.Scintilla.Text](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/blob/f4a1be4df11580071b77dfe16b01893a738d1f03/src/ScintillaNET/Scintilla.cs#L5150)

Then, you can use .NET [System.IO.File.WriteAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8) method or equivalents to save it to a disk file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\path\filename.txt", YourScintillaControlName.Text);
```